# Calling PHP file via AJAX, passing $_GET variable into MySQL query, then echoing into response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So I have this jQuery AJAX call that activates when I click on any of the divs with the class="username" attribute, which contains a user's username, like:

```
<div class="username">Sneaky</div>
```

Here's the jQuery AJAX call:

```
var usersName = '';
$('#chatContainer').delegate('div.username', 'click', function(e) {
    usersName = $(this).text();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'profile_popup.php',
        data: { usersName: usersName },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#profilePopup").show().offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY}).html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Here's the PHP file that it calls:

```
include 'MySQL_connect.php';

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['usersName']);

$sql = "SELECT chat_color FROM users WHERE username='$name'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$chatColor = $row["chat_color"];

$sql = "SELECT profile_pic FROM profiles WHERE username='$name'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$profilePic = $row["profile_pic"];

echo "<div style='color:$chatColor'>$name</div>
        <img style='height:64px' src='../profile/profile_pictures/$profilePic'>";
```

My problem is that it returns with no error but without the MySQL database values, like so:

```
<div id="profilePopup">
     <div style="color:"> Sneaky</div>
     <img src="../profile/profile_pictures/" style="height:64px">
</div>
```

Any clues as to why this isn't working as intended? I've done quite a lot with jQuery, PHP and MySQL on this site and this seems like it should work correctly.

Comment: can you add `dataType:'text',` in ajax?

Comment: @guradio Just tried that, and there's no difference in output.

Comment: can you anything in response of ajax?by the way your echo is not concatenated properly. `".$name."`

Comment: @guradio You actually don't need to concatenate your PHP variables in a string as long as they're in double quotes. I had it set up that way before I changed it to how it is, and the output was the same.

Comment: what does reponse give to you then?if you check it in network?

Comment: Can you give a few sample rows of your database schema and data?

Comment: @LFlare this is how my profiles table is set up: http://puu.sh/ox9Za/e110618287.png

Comment: @guradio the response is output as that last block of code in my original post, the $name variable works but the rest don't work.

Comment: Just changed the PHP file to $name = 'Sneaky'; then ran the file directly, and it worked. I'm really not sure why that works but the response doesn't.

Comment: @Sneaky, can you screenshot both the users and profiles tables?

Comment: @LFlare Yup, here's the users table: http://puu.sh/oxaMy/37f2a7b0c0.png I was trying to avoid that one because of the password md5's :P

Comment: @Sneaky, just to confirm, the user that is used to connect to the tables HAVE access privileges to the tables right? If so, can you add your MySQL_Connect.php? Just remove your authentication details.

Comment: @LFlare Yep, the user has the privileges. I use the same MySQL_connect.php file on every page that I need to push or pull variables from, and it works fine. Here's the file if you're still interested: http://puu.sh/oxbc3/a4dad73f99.png

Comment: @Sneaky i saw your table the column sound_setting has comma i am not against it but i wont recommend it either..just a thought

Comment: @Sneaky youve share your table can you share what the reponse of ajax is?

Comment: @guradio here's the response: http://puu.sh/oxbsG/867b131312.png and about the sound_settings column, it's fine, because I just explode and implode those values via "," then check if they're there when setting the variables later. it works :P

Comment: instead of `dataType : 'text',` change to `dataType:'html',`. yeah it works but putting 2 values in one column just isnt really recommended

Comment: @guradio Just tried that too, also no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I did some testing, and after checking what the javascript "usersName" variable was set to, I noticed that there was a space at the beginning. I don't know why, or how it got there, but it was there. I just did a quick workaround in the PHP file as follows:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['usersName']);
$name = ltrim($name," ");
```

This simply trims the whitespace from the beginning of the string. Thanks for all the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't bite me if I'm wrong, assuming all your SQL codes are correct, can you try

```
echo "<div style='color:" . $chatColor . "'>" . $name . "</div>
    <img style='height:64px' src='../profile/profile_pictures/" .     $profilePic . "'>";
```

-- EDIT --
Perhaps edit your PHP file to:

```
include 'MySQL_connect.php';

$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['usersName']);

$sql = "SELECT `chat_color`, `profile_pic` FROM users LEFT JOIN profiles ON (`users`.`username` = `profiles`.`username`) WHERE `username` = '" . $name . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$chatColor = $row['chat_color'];
$profilePic = $row['profile_pic'];

echo "<div style='color:$chatColor'>$name</div>
    <img style='height:64px' src='../profile/profile_pictures/$profilePic'>";
```

Comment: That's actually what I had before I changed it to what it currently is. :P But if you notice, the response actually includes the $name variable the way it is, so the rest of them should work that was as well. No biting, at least you tried. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

**PHP**

```
$text='<div style="color:'.$chatColor.'">'.$name.'</div>
<img style="height:64px"src="../profile/profile_pictures/'.$profilePic .'">';
echo '{"item" :'.json_encode($text).'}';
```

**AJAX**

```
success: function(data) {
    obj=$.parseJSON(data);
    $("#profilePopup").show().offset({left:e.pageX,top:e.pageY}).html(obj.item);
}
```

Comment: Tried this, just got an error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Comment: change " as ' i edited my answer and tried ... it is working.... if the sql results are correct it should work...

Comment: Ok, that got rid of the error but the output is exactly the same as before. I must've had a typo when I tried before :P